# Swipeable tabs with Fragments (API19+)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost

[image]

The goal is to:

- Have an `Activity` with tabs and `Fragments` (as content);
- Being able to swipe between `Fragments`;
- **Do not** use any support libraries (API 19+);

Was going for `TabHolder`. But is it possible to load `Fragment` as a content for it without `ViewPager`?

Comment: why not using tablayout with viewpager?

Comment: I don't want to support users that are below API 19 - don't want `AppCompat` or `support.v4`. I want to use most up to date tools, but haven't found enough documentation whether it is possible to slide without using `ViewPager`.